# Tomcat7 JAAS does not run LoginModule or raises errors

Tags: java, web, tomcat7, jaas

I'm trying to get JAAS working for a web app in Tomcat 7. I'm using form based authentication, a custom LoginModule and the tomcat JAASRealm, and I got everything to work except that seems like my LoginModule never gets invoked.
I've got my tomcat installation on c:\tomcat_home\7.0 and I'm running the project in eclipse with the following JVM arguments in the launch configuration:

```
-Dcatalina.base="C:\Users\user\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1"
-Dcatalina.home="C:\tomcat_home\7.0" 
-Dwtp.deploy="C:\Users\user\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps"
-Djava.endorsed.dirs="C:\tomcat_home\7.0\endorsed"
-Djava.security.auth.login.config="C:\tomcat_home\7.0\conf\jaas.config"
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
-Djava.util.logging.config.file="C:\tomcat_home\7.0\conf\logging.properties"
```

which has the default eclipse JVM args plus java.util.logging flags and the java.security.auth.login.config flag for the JAAS config file.

Now, every time I access a secured url JAAS I get redirected to the login page as expected, but when I submit the user and password I get the login fail page, even though my LoginModule is not making any checks - I've set it to always authenticate.
Also I filled the LoginModule with System.out calls and debug breakpoints but, even though I'm running tomcat in debug mode, I get no output in the console and the execution never stops at the breakpoints.
Besides that, I cleared the configuration file - jaas.config - in the hope that I'd get an exception, but Tomcat starts normally and the same authentication behaviour is observed.

The question is: how to make sure my LoginModule and the jaas configuration are being picked up? Does Tomcat 7 JAASRealm has a default LoginModule implementation?

Any help is appreciated.

**web.xml**

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>app</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>auth</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-role>
    <role-name>auth</role-name>
</security-role>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsf</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/loginFail.jsf</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

**jaas.config**

```
secureApp {
  com.mycompany.security.jaas.JPALoginModule required;
};
```

**META-INF/context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm" appName="secureApp"
    userClassNames="com.mycompany.security.jaas.UserPrincipal" roleClassNames="com.mycompany.security.jaas.RolePrincipal" />
</Context>
```

Comment: No.. not really. In the end I dropped the idea of using JAAS and moved to Apache Shiro.

Comment: tried to follow this tutorial

[http://wearethetech.com/2011/05/29/jaas-configuration-for-tomcat/](http://wearethetech.com/2011/05/29/jaas-configuration-for-tomcat/)